# Поместить метку [flex] в чёрный список

Tags: предложение, метки, чёрный-список-меток

Данная метка [flex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex) иногда воскресает, хотя я вопросы по ней замененял на [flexbox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flexbox) или [apache-flex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-flex) или на [flexbox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flexbox) в зависимости от смысла. Предлагаю её занести в чёрный список.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз уж сейчас по ней вопросов нет, предлагаю просто сделать её синонимом для [flexbox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flexbox).

Собственно, так и сделал.

PS: Ждём сутки, а то что-то странное получилось...

Comment: В принципе учитывая что Flash уверенно вымирает и количество вопросов по нему должно сокращаться, решение очень даже хорошее.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, сколько уже лет хоронят Flash? По-моему, не менее пяти.

Comment: @Arhad 10-й год это слышу. Уже Сильверлайт появился и сдох за это время, а flash всё ещё шевелится.

Comment: @Arhad Вообще-то использование Flash резко сократилось, а это свидельствует о его вымирании. Даже статья есть на блоге https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/08/01/flash-dead-technologies-might-next/ Там кстати об Apache Flex тоже говорится.

Comment: @Arhad официальные похороны (от Adobe) назначены на конец 2020. Да и за последние годы я не видел ни одного нового и развивающегося продукта на этой платформе. Игры успешно ушли на HTML5, разве что Scaleform UI в некоторых AAA остался. Видеоплееры на крупных хостингах перешли на HTML5. Для привыкших к API ещё есть haxe + OpenFL со сборкой в HTML5 или в тот же флэшовый байткод.