# Удаление синонима для метки flexbox

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Метка [flex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex) используется как синоним для другой метки - [flexbox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flexbox). В то же самое время мы могли бы использовать первую для [flex](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2)).

Comment: Именно на мете такие вопросы и нужно поднимать (:

Answer (score 3):

Вообще, есть же [lex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lex) для вопросов про лексические анализаторы.

По поводу [flex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex) же. Тут всё зависит от того, как люди используют. Хотя я, в целом, не считаю, что синонимизация [flex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex) к [flexbox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flexbox) была хорошей идей. Но если люди, употребляю [flex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex), подразумевают [flexbox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flexbox), то, думаю, синоним имеет место быть.

Comment: Про [tag:lex] никогда бы не догадался...

Answer (score 0):

### Я категорически не согласен

До этого вопроса уже было [обсуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6946/220571), где было принято решение сделать метку синонимом метки [flexbox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flexbox). До этого обсуждения эта метка была вполне самостоятельной, но не было ни одного вопроса, где метка употреблялась в значении технологии, которую вы упоминаете. Данное решение было принято на основании использований метки, а не было просто "притянуто за уши". Люди чаще всего использовали именно так эту метку, в основном имя ввиду Flexbox. Значительно реже имелась ввиду уже мёртвая технология [apache-flex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-flex) (изначально этой метки не было). Других значений изначально не встречалось.

Если вы считаете, что это надо поменять, то пожалуйста, приведите статистику или хотя бы пару примеров вопросов, которые бы заслужили данную метку. Обоснуйте, почему надо сделать, как вы предлагаете? Кроме того, что в природе существует технология, названная flex (хотя и для этого можно придумать более специфическую метку, которая не создаст проблем с однозначностью и как её использовать). В чём выгода данного решения?

P. S. Погуглите "flex" — очень много упоминания Flexbox найдёте.

Comment: Я не стану с Вами спорить о статистике - даже не зная таковой, я абсолютно уверен, что Вы правы, и гораздо больше людей интересуется flex'ом как технологией связанной с CSS, нежели с лексическими анализаторами.  На счет выгоды - не могу ответить на этот вопрос, я просто хотел бы, чтобы вещи назывались своими именами - если это CSS , то - flexbox, если лексический анализ - flex. Подытожу: я не настаиваю на том, что нужно удалить этот alias, я только предложил :)

Comment: @isnullxbh Метку так не будут использовать, как вы предложили. Посмотрите на родственную метку [tag:grid]. Будет в основном что-то связанное с CSS и небольшая разнородная кучка чего-то другого. Не хочется ещё одну метку-свалку.